# Running npm throws doesn't have permission

Tags: react-native, npm

So I am running `npm install` in my `react-native` project and error is thrown:

```
EACCES current user ("toma") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/10.20.0"
```

I working with `root` user and don't understand why it is saying that the current user is `toma`.
Any suggestions ? P.S. OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: what's the output of the command `whoami`?

Comment: I saw that but is it the right way ? It seems like "bypassing" the problem.